# How to optimize delete older records after the first N records?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I use `postgres` at work and there is a table `queries` using `btree` as pkey index

```
TABLE queries (
  id serial
  ... other fields
)
```

We have a query want to delete elements older than first N elements, The query looks like this, and `$1` is `N`.

```
DELETE FROM queries
WHERE id < COALESCE(
  (
    SELECT min(id)
    FROM (
      SELECT id
      FROM queries
      ORDER BY id DESC
      LIMIT $1
    ) ids
  ),
  0
);
```

The `EXPLAIN` result for this query is

```
Delete on queries  (cost=174908.32..322825.71 rows=272064 width=6)
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=174908.31..174908.32 rows=1 width=8)
          ->  Limit  (cost=0.42..168658.31 rows=500000 width=8)
                ->  Index Only Scan Backward using queries_pkey on queries queries_1  (cost=0.42..275314.52 rows=816191 width=8)
  ->  Seq Scan on queries  (cost=0.00..147917.39 rows=272064 width=6)
        Filter: (id < COALESCE($0, '0'::bigint))
```

This query takes quite a while in our PROD env with `N = 5e5`. There is a seq scan, but I don't really know where does it come from, nor how to optimize it. Isn't there already an index on `id`, and it seems that `id` is the only thing we are comparing? Or there is a different query to achieve my original goal?

Comment: We could use a little more information about this table and its indexes. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` to see where the time is spent (careful, it will execute the `DELETE`).

The execution plan looks reasonable, and if you experience problems with as little as 500000 rows, I'd bet that the table is referenced by [foreign keys that are not indexed](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/index-your-foreign-key/).